# GoogleAppEngine App for XML processing using JAVA

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script

I am currently developing a web application that gets input from the user using a GUI and generates an XML document out of it. After it is done, I need to upload this app to the Google app engine. I have also heard about Google App Script which will use JavaScript to create GUI based applications.

Will Google app engine support applications developed using Google app Script?

Kindly help me out in that.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no. Apps written using Google Apps Script run independently of App Engine although both of them run on Google's servers